# How can it be faster to compare the values between the columns of df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df, which needs to be recalculated about `100,000 times`, and `cannot` use `multi-process`, `multi-threading`, etc., see `sort_df()` for my demo of the comparison function.

My actual `df` is the `same length` as `generate_df()`, with `more columns`, `sort_df()` needs to compare `more columns`, the `actual running time` is about `600 seconds`, and my `demo` running time is `92 seconds`.

How can I `optimize my sort_df()` faster?

I also asked a question about the complete scene:
[How can I optimize the three methods in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417573/)

It would be great to be able to solve one of these two problems.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from tqdm import tqdm


def generate_df():
    durations = [60, 300, 900, 1800, 3600, 7200, 86400, 172800, 604800, 2592000]
    df = pd.DataFrame(durations, columns=['durations'])
    df['a'] = np.random.random(len(df)) * 10
    df['b'] = np.random.random(len(df)) * 10
    return df


def sort_df(df):
    df['a_great_than_b'] = df.a.to_numpy() >= df.b.to_numpy()
    df['a_less_than_b'] = ~df.a_great_than_b.to_numpy()
    return df


def main():
    total_time = 0
    n = 100000
    for _ in tqdm(range(n), total=n):
        df = generate_df()
        start_time = time.time()
        df = sort_df(df)
        end_time = time.time()
        total_time += end_time - start_time
    print(total_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
100%|██████████| 100000/100000 [03:16<00:00, 510.14it/s]
92.62787532806396
```

```
df=generate_df()
%timeit sort_df(df)
```

```
382 µs ± 5.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Your `sort_df()` just creates data columns which you never use.  We can't optimize this, because it's a trivial function that does nothing really useful.  If you post a more complete/realistic example program, maybe we can speed that up.

Comment: I found this function with the longest running time based on the cumtime of cProfile. There is also a function that uses df. I have already asked the question before. If two questions need to be combined, it may take a few hours before I have time to post the question.

Comment: The problem is you're asking us to optimize something which is absolutely trivial.  Like "Optimize A+B".  A+B can't really be optimized, but maybe if we see the larger context we can figure out how to avoid doing A+B at all.

Comment: Then I will post the complete content later. thanks

Comment: I reposted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417573/how-can-i-optimize-the-three-methods-in-my-code

Comment: Although you think my question is simple, if you can answer it, I would be very grateful.